# Changing the name of [.imageset] is not recognized by Git

Tags: ios, swift, git, sourcetree

I am currently working with iOS project with version control Git + SourceTree. I have one problem that when I changing the name of imageset (inside Assets.xcassets folder), Git is not marked as unstaged file(dirty files). For example, changing the name from `icon.imageset` to `icon_new.imageset`. However, if I add new imageset, Git now recognized this new added file and marked as unstaged and of course, it allow me to commit it as well.

I here attached my `ignore file`. I am not so sure it is the reason or it's the bug of Xcode. Hope anyone can give some hints or solution so that I can continue to rename all my imageset.

```
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## Build generated
build/
DerivedData

## Various settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata

## Other
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
*.xcuserstate
*.xcscmblueprint

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap
*.ipa

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
Pods/

# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.
# Carthage/Checkouts

Carthage/Build

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo. Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the 
# screenshots whenever they are needed.

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/screenshots
```

**Update 1:** 
after calling `git status --ignored`, I then get the following result.

```
.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Alamofire/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Notifications.swift
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Timeline.swift
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/DeviceKit/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Google/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/GoogleUtilities/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Headers/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper/Core/Mappable.swift
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/hsuan.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/DeviceKit.xcscheme
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/hsuan.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/QRCode.xcscheme
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/QRCode/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/SQLite.swift/SQLite/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/SQLite.swift/podstuff/
    SwiftTestProject/Pods/Target Support Files/
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/Base.lproj/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/BaseClass/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/DBHandler/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/DataObjects/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/DataObjects/CustomedTransform/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/Login/
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/Utilities/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/VppViewController/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/WebAPI/.DS_Store
    SwiftTestProject/SwiftTestProject/.DS_Store
```

Does the line

```
iBonSwift/iBonSwift/Assets.xcassets/.DS_Store
```

causing problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. After changing the name of the folder, command `git status` marks the old folder as "deleted", and the new folder as "untracked". You can use `git status --ignored` to get more info about ignored files.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, thxs for replaying. i have tried and updated the post for the result. Hope you have time to point me again.

Comment: To answer your edit: No, it doesn't. As far as I can see, the change of the folder name should be tracked by git. To clarify: Xcode does not mark the status of the inner folders within `Assets.xcassets` folder - since we cannot disclose it in the navigator view.